# How to remove some tags from BIG HTML string?

Tags: java, android, html, list

I need to work with some HTML Tags (remove them)

This HTML is stored as a .txt into my app's assets folder

This HTML is so big (like 7.000+ lines) that I couldn't store it into a simple String var...

I'm using this code to convert the .txt to an ArrayList:

```
InputStream is;

try {
    is = getAssets().open("html.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String strLine;

List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        stringList.add(strLine);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This way, I guess each line from the .txt HTML is stored as a stringList's element... But how could I remove the wanted tags, given that its beginning and ending may be in different lines?

If it is impossible, I would like to know any workaround for this issue... Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I want to make modifications like removing all links from the page, like `<a href="url">` to `<a>`

also, I want to remove the tag `<title>`... Resuming: those aren't big modifications...

I already work with JSoup in one of my projects... But it just stores the HTML as a Document... To work with the tags, being the HTML in a Document type is worth? And how could I convert the .txt file in a JSoup Document?

Comment: Are you sure you can't store the HTML in a string? Lines isn't much of a metric. How many bytes or characters is it? Post sample HTML showing the kind of removal you want to make?

Comment: JSoup is a library for parsing html content: https://jsoup.org/

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman yes I'm sure, the .txt files has 500KB and 492.746 characters... The compiler says `error: constant string too long` I will post an example

Comment: @ThalesLima this only means you can't hardcode the content in your .java file. When reading the file you can put it all in the same `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` and  have all the html in a single `String` variable. I'm just saying this is technically possible, not that it's a good approach.

Comment: The maximum length of a String constant is shorter than the maximum length of a String in Java. You could potentially read the file directly into a String (lots of ways to do that). 500KB isn't that large. Still not an ideal solution, but might be the simplest, particularly if this isn't production code that will have to run on future files of unknown size.

Comment: @jlordo Whoa, I didn't notice that the error was ONLY about constant Strings... But I guess I will try to do it using an HTML parser, as Geoffrey said... What would be the best Object to convert my String and work with the JSoup HTML parser? Document, String, InputStream? And how could I convert my .txt to those Object types?

Comment: Why not use JSoup to also pare your file: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.io.File-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really can't store it all in a big string (or you don't want to), extracting content that could span lines will be a problem, yes.

Rather than leap to a list of strings, have you considered looking at an HTML parser, ideally one that supports streaming and modification?

The reason why you might consider an HTML parser is that manually searching HTML for tags could fail to consider all of the potential scenarios you might encounter (commented out HTML tags and other things that an HTML parser could handle for you).